# android with php web service

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am developing an android app with php for web service. In my application i have insert, update, delete and search query in php file and saved into www root and then I called php file into android app. Search function is working  well,but Delete function is not working. I have attached the php file , android code and Error also.can any one help me ???

```
 **filename** (deletedetail.php)

<?php
include "config.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql1="delete from detail where id ='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($sql1);

 if($result)
{
  echo"OK";
}
  else
{
  echo "Error";

}

?>






**android CODE**

public String deleteDetail(int id) { 
        try {

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/dreamhotel/deletedetail.php"); // change this to your URL.....
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",Integer.toString(id)));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);       


        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
        return response;  
    }
```

**`Error in Android`**

```
at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
```

Comment: Try commenting out that System.out.println and see what happens, if you get an error, please post the whole logcat message.

Comment: please add ur full logcat, and Instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` use `Log.e(e.toString);`

Answer (score 0):

Please use HTTP GET method instead of HTTP POST and for HTTP GET method url should be.

```
http://10.0.2.2/dreamhotel/deletedetail.php?id=1
```

and make some chnage server side : user server side $_GET or $_REQUEST instead of $_POST.

See below I edited your code.

```
<?php
include "config.php";

//$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql1="delete from detail where id ='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($sql1);

 if($result)
{
  echo"OK";
}
  else
{
  echo "Error";

}

?>
```